# file.delete() error 30

Tags: android, file, text-files, delete-file

I try to delete a text file I created with:

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("game.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

by using

```
File file = new File(filename);
        if (!file.exists())
        {
        Log.d(TAG,"gonna delete game.txt");
        file.delete();
        }
```

but keep getting error message:

> Unable to unlink '/game.txt': Read-only file system (errno=30)

Do you know what's wrong here?

Comment: is `game.txt` in the root ( / ) folder?

Comment: you have added write permission in manifest ? is the file being created? and value of filename?

Comment: game.txt is in root folder. And I've found solution. Filename should have contained full path to file. Now it works fine

Comment: uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" try to add this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now it works well. Filename did not contain full path to file (although it's in root directory) it has to have full path

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(filename);

if (file.exists()){
    Log.d(TAG,"gonna delete game.txt");  
     file.delete(); }
```

Try this.